# Override Word Paste event - VSTO

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, vsto

I am working on a Word custom ribbon bar add-in and I need to override the **Word Paste event** and do something more to the pasting range. My current implementation is as follows.

In the `ribbon.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load" >
  <commands>
    <command idMso="Paste" onAction="RegenerateIDsAfterPaste"/>
  </commands>
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
     ........
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

In the `ribbon.cs` file,

```
public void RegenerateIDsAfterPaste(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
{
    Word.Selection selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
    Word.Range range = selection.Range;
    range.Paste();
    //more code here
}
```

With the current implementation, when I paste the content in the clipboard using **Ctrl+V**, it works well and apply the changes to the pasting range as implemented in the `RegenerateIDsAfterPaste` method.

But when I try to paste the content in the clipboard by right clicking on the Word document and clicking the below 1st button, the `RegenerateIDsAfterPaste` method doesn't even execute. Seems the `idMso=Paste` doesn't represent this button click.
[image]

I tried some other idMso vaues related to Paste added in this [link](https://onlinehelp.ribboncreator.de/EN/_2hm0n9inj.htm). But none of them worked.

Does anybody have an idea on how should I modify my code so that it works with both `Ctrl+V` and "Word right click Paste".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may be looking to intercept the EditPaste command. This can be done with a vba procedure named EditPaste. See https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm

Comment: We have already tried the 'EditPaste' VBA procedure. It also doesn't work on Word right click Paste. 
Aslo when we use that 'EditPaste' command, the pasting into Envelop and Label fields of the Word Mailings tab will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official list of ids here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

The one you are looking for is probably `PasteSourceFormatting`

Comment: `PasteSourceFormatting` is not working as well. And I tried the paste related ids from the provided list, none of them worked for me. What I tried was adding this line within the <commands> tag along with the previous one.
`<command idMso="PasteSourceFormatting" onAction="RegenerateIDsAfterPaste"/>`